# Sound Classification of Ausculations

Tags: audio, signals

I have been collecting audio waves of ausculations from a digital stethoscope and am trying to classify the sounds into normal or dysfunctional for a proof of concept. I am working with a small data set. At the moment N=30. I'd really like to find a way to do a quick proof of concept. Unlike regular music, each normal sound may vary slightly by patient.

I have collected the data and performed FFT on them but now am a bit stuck. Not sure which direction to go. It seems as if the ideal long term path would be to do semi-supervised deep learning:

1. Collect data
2. Randomly select a % for labeling
3. Prepare data for denoising auto encoding with Theano
4. Train some 2 support vector classifiers for normal vs. dysfunctional

Is there a simpler way for a proof of concept? I am new to both Python and machine learning and am willing to hunker down and do what's necessary. I need to figure out if this is viable and would appreciate any tips.